# pywebview. Как переключить фокус на основное окно программы?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, многопоточность, focus, pywebview

Использовал **[pywebview](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/guide/installation.html#dependencies)** для отображения веб-страниц внутри программы.
Столкнулся с проблемой: при создании окна **webview** основное окно программы становится **неактивным**, причем манипуляции с ним (перемещение) запоминаются и **воспроизводятся после закрытия окна webview.**
Попробовал пустить через **поток**, вероятно не правильно использовал.
Кто сталкивался, как решить эту проблему? Нужно чтоб основное окно **не блокировалось окном webview**.
Минимальный код ниже. Для работы необходимы установленные: **PyQt5, PyWebview**.

(известный вариант с PyQtWebEngine не предлагайте, работает только на х64 и при инсталяции/деинсталяции вышибает рабочую PyQt5).

```
from threading import Thread
import sys
import webview
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 200)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('<h1>Double Click Me!</h1>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('background-color: #5599ff;')

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        thread_func()

def thread_func():
    webview.start(win2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win2 = webview.create_window('tst_win_2', html='text2', width=400, height=300)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    thread = Thread(target=thread_func)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связался с разработчиком **PyWebview**, действительно имеет место быть такая проблема. Особенность GUI.
Решается задача через **мультипроцессинг**.
Накидал корявенкий код, но суть решения отражает.

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import webview

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f'<h1>Main window</h1>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pass

def gui_main(): # функция с процессом основной программы
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def gui_bro(): # функция с процессом создания окна pywebview
    win2 = webview.create_window('tst_win_2', html='text2', width=400, height=300)
    webview.start(win2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gui_main)
    proc1.start()
    proc2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gui_bro, daemon=True)
    proc2.start()
    proc1.join()
```